# Syntax for adding an integer to a buffer nasm

Tags: linux, string, assembly, x86, nasm

thank you all of you for the help i really appreciate it.
i have done my best to locate a solution in the forum and online however i am only finding information specifically for converting string to int and int to string but i am questioning my syntax and would like to know what is wrong with it.

i have a hopefully quick question, is this the correct syntax for adding an integer to a buffer: " add dword [userScore], 6 " or do i have to convert the contents of the userScore buffer to integer then add and in registers then convert the resulting int back into string to insert back into the userScore?

Comment: Explain what your buffer contains, please. Be specific, for example explain buffer length. Because "buffer" is a very broad word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what's in that buffer?

```
add dword [userScore], 6
```

Adds 6 to the dword at the address `userScore` (which is of course exactly what it looks like it's doing), so the rest of the code should treat it as a dword also.

If there is a string in there, as a suspect there is otherwise you wouldn't be asking this question, then adding an integer to it doesn't really mean much. You can get lucky (or unlucky, from a debugging perspective), because the characters for 0 through 9 are assignment to char values in order, so if you add a small number to a string it may look like you got away with it. But it doesn't work in general, for example if you add 1 (integer) to a `'9'` (character), you get a `':'` character.

You could do math on the string directly (that's not exactly hard, but a lot more complicated than
`add dword [variable], something`), or as you suggest temporarily convert the string to an integer in order to do math on it, but the more usual solution is to store that variable as an integer and only convert it to a string when displaying it.